# javascript output disappearing

Tags: javascript

```
 function init(){
    var flag=true;
    if(flag)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "power is on<br />";
    }
    if(7<2)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "<br />failure";
    }
        if(2<7)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "<br />success";
    }
}
window.onload=init;
```

this is if.js i load it in another html file, but this is the main code that is run.

the only output i am getting is "success" being written but the "power is on" is not showing up what is wrong?

Comment: Your second call to  `document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=` replaces the content of the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assign innerHTML in multiple places, make a string and assign it at once.

```
var flag = true,
    html = "";
if (flag) {
    html += "power is on<br />";
}
if (7 < 2) {
    html += "<br />failure";
}
if (2 < 7) {
    html += "<br />success";
}
document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var panel =  document.getElementById("panel");
    if(flag) {
        panel.innerHTML += "power is on<br />";
    }

    if(7<2) {
        panel.innerHTML += "<br />failure";
    }
    if(2<7) {
        panel.innerHTML += "<br />success";
    }
```

every time you change the `innerHTML` you overwrite all the previous content, so you have to append the string with `+=`.

Maybe you may want to to also create a reference to panel element just once.

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ypznU/

Comment: `+= innerHTML`, need I say more?

Comment: @Esailija yes: what's wrong with it? :) I hope this is not due for a matter of micro-optimization on appending two strings (even if you're absolutely right on this).

Comment: +1,and Esailja mean that innerHTML forces DOM to redraw everything therefore you should use it as minimum as you can

Comment: @Random depending on browser, a simple loop can run for 6 minutes using `+= innerHTML` vs a few milliseconds if you use buffer string. It's not about += with strings, it's about += specifically with innerHTML which means serializing DOM and reparsing the HTML constantly which is very very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the current HTML in there, you should be using += instead of =.

```
function init(){
var flag=true;
if(flag)
{
    document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML +=
        "power is on<br />";
}
if(7<2)
{
    document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML +=
        "<br />failure";
}
    if(2<7)
{
    document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML +=
        "<br />success";
}
```

How does this work for you?

Comment: I think you were downvoted by the user who correctly pointed out that strings should be computed once before append them via innerHTML. Anyway in this specific case I think it's more important show and explain to the user why the previous strings have been deleted, so +1 for me

Comment: Yes, that is probably why I was downvoted, and they were right, it is better to build the string and then assign it in one go. But this showed why your text wasn't appearing how you expected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `innerHTML` of an element *replaces* whatever contents it had previously with the given HTML string. So what's happening is that "power is on" is visible for an instant (computers are really fast these days) and then immediately replaced with "success".

Answer (score 0):

You can use else if instead of if

```
function init(){
    var flag=true;
    if(flag)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "power is on<br />";
    }
    else if(7<2)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "<br />failure";
    }
        else if(2<7)
    {
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
            "<br />success";
    }
}
window.onload=init;
```

Please note above code always display "power is on" because in your method you assign flag as true, if you want multiple output you can use concatenation approach as other suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The last if-statement will always evaluate to true.

```
if(2<7)
{
    document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=
        "<br />success";
}
```

This means that "success" will always replace whatever is inside the panel element.
Make sure that your conditional is really what you want and that replacing is really what you intended. Otherwise append the string like others has suggested.